# ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel in VB Application upon Database Reboot

Tags: vb.net, oracle, database-connection

I have made a windows service using VB that listens for incoming requests for specific data from table and provides data to the client. The application works fine; however, at night we are disconnecting the database for a while to make backup. And then the database is started again. However, the windows service is not restarted. The next day when any client requests for the data, I am getting ORA-03113; end-of-file on communication channel Exception which occurs at this line

```
connection.Execute("my query goes here")
```

I have even tried to put a check like the following as soon as I get any request from client for data.

```
If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
       connection.Open()
End If
```

Can anyone guide me here what exactly I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: don't disconnect the database to do a hot backup. Hot backups have been out there for more than 10 years. Or do you have a specific reason to do a offline backup?

Comment: Well. I am not a database administrator here so I am not aware of the reasons of why making offline backup. But I guess there must be some reasons why they chose hot backup. Is there any way I can handle this issue in my VB windows service??

Comment: Are you using connection pooling, or is your application opening a single connection and leaving it open indefinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach for database communication (IMHO) is this one.

1. Create Connection
2. Connect
3. Create command
4. Execute query
5. Dispose command
6. Dispose connection

That seems to be a lot overhead and a performance killer to create a connection for every query. However, most .NET Dataproviders support pooling, so basically the open connection is still there and valid and will be recycled upon next request.

This approach is way better than performing a `connection.State` since you can't 100% rely on this and is faster than doing a `TnsPing` for every query.

Connection Pooling for oracle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719767(v=vs.71).aspx

Example code:

```
Public Static Readonly ConnectionString = "Data Source=MyOracleServer;Integrated Security=yes;"
Public Shared Function ExecuteScalar(of T)(string commandString)

    Using con As new OracleConnection(connectionString)

       con.Open()

       Using cmd As new OracleCommand(con, commandString)

           Return CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), T)

       End Using

    End Using ' this one will call con.Dispose() which will close the connection

End Function
```

With this simple code you have a connectionless approach like you would have it with a website that communicates with your db. All you need is clever exception handling (which shouln't be to hard with a service application. Just use a global exception handler, dump exceptions to the eventlog and retry later.

Comment: Thanks.. I was exactly thinking the same before I read your comment. I will surely try this.. I was actually not sure whether it will cause a lot overhead.. I'll accept the answer as soon as I get results. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try incorporating a TNSPING into your VB.net code.
There appears to be a few pointers on how to do this on the interweb.
Basically, using vb.net to run a script file and interpreting the redirected output from file.

Comment: `tnsping` won't tell you if the database is down, only if the listener is responding; and certainly not if it has been bounced (i.e. was down, but is now back up).

Comment: This is the issue with me. The server gets turned off at night while it is taking backup and then it is restarted in the morning.. TNSPING is not working in this case for me..